# One Schengen-visa question to rule them all

Tags: discussion

We have currently [104 questions about Schengen visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schengen+visas), and admittedly that's way too much. Invariably, most of them are very similar -- for example, duration of multiple entry visa, point-of-entry different from issuing country, etc. You have seen them, and even an acronym popped up NASQ -- Not Another Schengen Question (thanks, @MarkMayo).

We do have some questions that are commonly selected as duplicates, but I think we can do better. A somewhat more comprehensive community wiki post (titled along the lines of "Everything you need to know about Schengen visas") which covers most of the issues we already have answers for, is what I'm proposing. There's no need to write everything from scratch -- existing answers can be reused without problem (attribution required, of course).

What you can do:

- **Comment and up/downvote** to show your support to this suggestion.
- **Answer** the question with specific questions or answers you feel are good enough and should be included in such CW post.

If people generally like the idea (or at least don't oppose it ferociously), I'll try to get started with this in the coming weeks.

Comment: 1056 questions later...

Answer (score 8):

Stuff that NEEDS to be included:

- Can I apply for a Schengen visa from my home country?
- Do I need a Schengen visa for every Schengen country I visit?
- When do I need a multi-entry Schengen visa?
- Do I need a Schengen visa for transit in a Schengen country?
- Can I extend my Schengen visa?
- Is it perhaps easier to stay at home than understand the Schengen visa system?
- How to tell if my Schengen visa is valid?
- Can I apply for a Schengen from outside my home country of citizenship / residency?

Answer (score 6):

This has to be done carefully. StackExchange requires that for a question to be marked as a duplicate, the **question** needs to be the same. If different questions have the **same** answer, that's not enough reason for being marked as duplicate.

Couple of ways around this:

- When you see a Schengen visa question, see if you can edit it to make it generic. Keep the OP's details in, and then perhaps add an edit at the bottom summing up the generic situation. This will allow questions to be marked a duplicate / merged.
- When a new Schengen visa question is asked, see if a duplicate exists and flag it as a dupe.

Comment: А lot of the questions closed as duplicates for Schengen-related issues are not quite the same - different countries, similar circumstances. Yet they are still closed as duplicates, even if one is about Denmark, and the other about Slovakia. I agree with you we should do it carefully not to end up in a greater mess than we start with, but still I think there's value in what I propose.

Comment: Hence why I say before closing as duplicate, add a generic version of the question to the mapped duplicate. OPs may not know that the rules are the same.

Comment: What @AnkurBanerjee said.  I see too many questions flagged duplicate when they are not.  Editing one to cover both would be helpful.  (Unfortunately, the author of the one that gets closed may still feel insulted.)

Answer (score 5):

PLEASE PLEASE DO THIS! Those questions are coming in by the second!

Some more:

- what factors influence my likelihood to get a Schengen visa
- single vs. multiple entry visa
- My application got rejected, what now?

Comment: I think it's great that we're getting them - we must be high on google search terms for schengen now. But yeah, there really is quite the influx these days :/